# How can I force Firefox to reset its DNS cache on-demand?

Tags: firefox, dns

I use [hostnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hostnames) to temporarily redirect certain hostnames to localhost when coding.

Problem is Firefox caches DNS entries for much longer than I would expect (`network.dnsCacheExpiration` has no effect).

How can I force Firefox to reset its DNS cache on-demand?

Answer (score 30):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me. It clears cached pages, but not dns entries.

Instead, I go to this URL: `about:networking#dns`, then click the Clear DNS Cache button.

I'm afraid I don't recall where I learned about that, but the existence of that button pretty clearly indicates that Mozilla intends it to be how you do this.

WHY THIS MATTERS: I sometimes modify my hosts file (Windows), then flush DNS in the OS (admin cmd prompt, `ipconfig /flushdns`. That typically works the first time I do it, but when I remove a host file entry to go back to the real address, Firefox doesn't pick it up without this.

Comment: Great answer; didn't know about `about:networking` and this button, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue (will submit a bug report to Firefox).

When `Enable DNS over HTTPS` is enabled, Firefox ignores entries in `/etc/hosts`.

Great security feature to enforce DNS over HTTPS, but I believe `localhost` should still resolve locally.

Bug report [submitted](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1611808).

Answer (score 2):

> According to [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1213045) thread on mozilla support by jscher2000:

"Clearing the cache is *supposed* to **clear both pages and DNS entries**.

Another way to flush the DNS cache might be to set it to a very small number of records:

**(1)** In a new tab, type or paste **about:config** in the address bar and press Enter/Return. Click the button promising to be careful or accepting the risk.

**(2)** In the search box above the list, type or paste **dns** and pause while the list is filtered

**(3)** Double-click the **network.dnsCacheEntries** preference and enter a low value such as 5 and click OK

**(4)** Leave network.dnsCacheExpiration and **network.dnsCacheExpirationGracePeriod** with their default values (you can right-click > Reset if needed)"

also,

You can remove all data stored in Firefox from a specific domain via "Forget About This Site" in the right-click context menu of an history entry ("History -> Show All History" or "View -> Sidebar -> History").

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why, but these settings don’t work for me... Even though `network.dnsCacheExpiration` is set to `60`, Firefox doesn’t follow my entries in `/etc/hosts`. Also, I was hopping for a way to clear the cache on-demand.

Comment: Found the issue (see my answer). Thanks for your help!